# Как в java полследоватльно выполнить комнады для командной строки?

Tags: windows, cmd, java

Пока получается только саму командную строку запустить

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd");
```

Допустим, нужно зайти в определенную папку и там выполнить несколько команд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то в этом роде:
`StringBuilder gitResetcmd = new StringBuilder();
                gitResetcmd.append("cmd /c \"cd\\ && cd users\\\\library");
                gitResetcmd.append("&& git reset --hard ");
                gitResetcmd.append(sha);
                gitResetcmd.append("\"");
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(gitResetcmd.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

По моему нужно просто открыть cmd отдельным процессом и перехватить его InputStream. Отсюда Example 2 посмотри: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Command_injection_in_Java